# j meter how to copy the redirect location

Tags: regex, jmeter, regression

I am sending some jmeter request and it responds with below details

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://testserver:80/v1/infos/text?ct=w.3-R-LE1
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 31 Dec 2019 12:24:56 GMT
Connection: close
Server: myserver
```

Now, I dont want to enable follow redirect option in Jmeter, I need to copy the Location in to 3 variables and use these variables in later requests.

portocal=https

redirectServer:testserver

redirecturl:/v1/infos/text?ct=w.3-R-LE1

I tried to add regular expression for response headers but not able to copy the required data in to these variables

```
Variable: Protocol 
Regular expression: "Location":"(.*?)", 

Variable: redirectServer
Regular expression: "Location https":"(.*?)", 


Variable: redirectUrl
Regular expression: "Location: https://testserver:80/":"(.*?)",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct regular expressions would be:

1. For protocol: `Location: (\w+):`

   [image]
2. For host and port: `Location:.*://(.+?)/`

   [image]
3. For path: `Location: (?:[^/]*(?:/(?:/[^/]*/?)?)?([^?]+)(?:\??.+)?)`

   [image]

Make sure to tick `Response Headers` as the "Field to check" and use `$1$` as the "Template"

[image]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Server and protocol working but url is not capturing the query params I want to url as  /v1/infos/text?ct=w.3-R-LE1 but it is giving only /v1/infos/text

Comment: C'mon, man, given `([^?]+)` is the group which returns URL path if you need to have the query string as well just change `?` to `*`.  Full regex just in case: `(?:[^/]*(?:/(?:/[^/]*/?)?)?([^*]+)(?:\??.+)?)`. If you have problems with creating regular expressions you might find [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter/) easier to use